# Toggling 3 pieces of text on a button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm building a website using a website building and looking to toggle three text values on a click of a button. This is to toggle between USD and GBP values. I have the following code to toggle one piece of text but not clear how to add two other pieces of text for standard and premium fees?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<p><button onclick="myFunction()">USD - GBP</button></p>

<div id="myDIV">Basic Fee $50</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Basic Fee $50") {
    x.innerHTML = "Basic Fee £60";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Basic Fee $50";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone is willing to help.

Comment: What are the other "*pieces of text*", and given that you've achieved basic functionality already, what are you struggling with when adding a third (or fourth, I'm not quite clear)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no server-side logic to store the prices in and retrieve them dynamically, then the most simple and extensible way to achieve this would be to populate the DOM with all the currency values. You can show the default currency and hide the other one. Then on click of the button you can `toggleClass()` to alternate as necessary.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $currencyValues = $('.currency-value');

  $('.currency-toggle').on('click', () => {
    $currencyValues.toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});

/*
// the same in plain JS:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let currencyValues = document.querySelectorAll('.currency-value');
  
  document.querySelector('.currency-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
    currencyValues.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('hidden'));
  });
});
*/
```

```css
.type {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.currency-value.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button class="currency-toggle">USD - GBP</button></p>
<div>
  <span class="type">Basic Fee</span>
  <span class="currency-value usd">$50</span>
  <span class="currency-value gbp hidden">£60</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="type">Handling Fee</span>
  <span class="currency-value usd">$75</span>
  <span class="currency-value gbp hidden">£100</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="type">Another Fee</span>
  <span class="currency-value usd">$100</span>
  <span class="currency-value gbp hidden">£125</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The script is doing as requested. Glad you understood what I am looking for. In terms of the website builder I'm using, it looks as though it only accepts html/JS. You have provided the JS but how is this incorporated into the script? I guess you have figured out I'm fairly new to this so do appreciate your patience.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the website builder you're using - but you can include the above JS code in the exact same way you had `myFunction()` deifned. Just remove that and replace it with either of the above scripts. The commented out plain JS can be transferred in directly without the need to add any other references (ie. jQuery.js)